# how to write a lua script using hddtemp so that results are displayed in a bargraph

Tags: conky

in my lua bargraph script I have

```
name="hddtemp",
arg="execi 100 hddtemp /dev/sda2 |cut -c33-40",
```

I just want the temperature to be displayed in a bar graph.
What I have written above displays an empty bargraph.
it also displays this message in the terminal.

```
conky: reading exec value failed (perhaps it's not the correct format?)
conky: could not connect to hddtemp host
```

Could someone please assist me and point me in the right direction so that I can write the correct script name and argument so as to display the hddtemp in a lua bargraph.
Thank you.

Comment: I see that Byte Commander took it upon himself to edit my question and yet offered no answer to my question. So what use were you?

Answer (score 0):

name="execi 10", 
 arg="hddtemp /dev/sda2 -n",
       max=100,
       alarm=80,

Writing this will allow one to read hddtemp in a bargraph. just rewrite sda2 so that it matches your drive number.